# How do i filter wrong inputs in python>

Tags: python, filter

Here is my code so far - I am simply trying to say that if the input isnt one of these words, to redo the loop. However, although 'monday' works, the other days dont.

run_day = input("On which day do you want your code to run? ")

```
while run_day.lower() != ("monday" or "tuesday" or "wednesday" or "thursday" or "friday" or "saturday" or "sunday"):
    run_day = input("On which day do you want your code to run? ")
```

Comment: Can you please explain your question a bit more?

Comment: `("monday" or "tuesday" or "wednesday" or "thursday" or "friday" or "saturday" or "sunday")` is *just `"monday"`*. While Python sometimes reads like natural language English, it isn't. Logical connectives don't automatically get distributed over. In natural language, we can say "I want a taco or a burger", but in Python, we have to say `choice == "taco" or choice == "burger"`